# Fragments and Listview Subitems

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments, subitem

I am currently having trouble with displaying my subitems in the list view.  I am unsure of what is causing this.  I've tried playing around with the `.put` but that was unsuccessful.

Here is my code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView lv_shifts;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("WorkMi");

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        lv_shifts = view.findViewById(R.id.shfits_lv);

        HashMap<String,String> day_Time = new HashMap<String, String>();
        day_Time.put("4/12/18","7AM - 2PM" );
        day_Time.put("4/14/18","5PM - 10PM" );
        day_Time.put("4/15/18","10AM - 2PM" );
        day_Time.put("4/16/18","7AM - 4PM" );
        day_Time.put("4/18/18","5AM - 2PM" );
        day_Time.put("4/21/18","7AM - 2PM" );

        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), listItems, R.layout.shift_list,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.date_tv, R.id.time_tv});

        Iterator it = day_Time.entrySet().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()){
            HashMap<String,String> resultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            resultMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());

            listItems.add(resultMap);
        }

        lv_shifts.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), listItems, R.layout.shift_list,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.date_tv, R.id.time_tv});` after while loop

Answer (score 0):

You were adding listItem to adapter before adding items to `listview` which is causing empty `listView`. Add your `while` loop before instantiating your adapter and then `setAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your data in simple view in one line. Why do you need a hashMap?

```
String[] day_Time = new String[] { "4/12/18  7AM - 2PM",
    "4/14/18 5PM - 10PM",
    "4/15/18 10AM - 2PM",
    "4/16/18 7AM - 4PM",
    "4/18/18 5AM - 2PM",
    "4/21/18  7AM - 2PM"}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, day_Time);

lv_shifts = view.findViewById(R.id.shfits_lv);

// Set Adapter to List View to display items
lv_shifts.setAdapter(adapter);
```